# What is the equivalent of OBJECT_NAME() in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have been working on an Oracle stored procedure and I need to add the equivalent of [OBJECT_NAME() (which works in MS SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in Oracle. Is there any dynamic way to do this in Oracle.

Comment: There is no obvious Oracle equivalent of this function. But what do you use it for? If you can explain its purpose we might be able to suggest a workaround.

Comment: I want to add the name of my procedure in the 'Created by ' column of a table. For that I was using Object_Name in SQL. Want to know whether there is any other way to this in Oracle apart from hard-coding it.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? Is this a standalone procedure or in a package?

Comment: Currently using Oracle 11g. Trying to run it in a package.